# Magento 2 delta migration skip catalog

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool

While sales data(customers/orders) keeps growing on the Magento 1 environment, the amount of products in the Magento 2 environment keeps growing as well. Now when I want to migrate the delta, I get errors from the Map step like:

`SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '22883-1' for key 'CATALOGINVENTORY_STOCK_ITEM_PRODUCT_ID_WEBSITE_ID'`

So the delta stumbles upon a duplicate entry MySQL error, because the incremental index on the Magento 2 side has grown faster than the incremental index on the Magento 1 side.

Anyway, I don't need to import products/categories/inventory stock. I tried excluding the Map step by commenting it in the config:

```xml
<step title="Customer Attributes Step">
    <delta>Migration\Step\Customer\Delta</delta>
    <volume>Migration\Step\Customer\Volume</volume>
</step>
<!-- Exclude this step...
<step title="Map Step">
    <delta>Migration\Step\Map\Delta</delta>
    <volume>Migration\Step\Map\Volume</volume>
</step>
<!-- -->
<step title="Log Step">
    <delta>Migration\Step\Log\Delta</delta>
    <volume>Migration\Step\Log\Volume</volume>
</step>
```

**Can I just exclude the Map step(containing the catalog migration) or do I need to do something else?**

Comment: Did you ever try this?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you choose the correct mode node:
`<steps mode="settings">`
or
`<steps mode="data">`
or
 `<steps mode="delta">`

Example path to file:
**vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.4.1/config.xml**